# Desktop environment that can pin a workspace to an external monitor

Tags: desktop-environment, laptop, multi-monitor, workspaces

Is it possible to "pin" the contents of one workspace to an external monitor (projector) while being able to see its content on the laptop's built-in screen?

I'm on Arch Linux and am ready to test any proposals.
I'm using Gnome and occasionally XFCE, but am open to other DE's.

Comment: Which window manager/desktop environment? This sounds like you want to a presentation - lots of software (like {Open,Libre}Office) for that is actually able to show a presenter screen on one display while showing the presentation on another.

Comment: I'm using Gnome and occasionally XFCE, but am open to other DE's. The problem with Libreoffice Impress is that I have to create a presentation and include my notes inside the presentation. I would like to use other programs for my notes and at the same time have the possibility of consulting other "material".

Answer (score 1):

Workspaces cover all monitors. Some window managers have very flexible notions of workspaces and let you program pretty much whatever you want ([Awesome](https://awesomewm.org/), [Sawfish](http://sawfish.tuxfamily.org/)), but even there I think you'd have to write some code to express this in terms of workspaces.

What you can do in many window managers is to make a window *sticky* across workspaces. This means that the window appears at the same position on all workspaces. If you put the presentation window(s) on the projector and make them sticky, and you don't put any other window on that monitor on any workspace, then you'll get the desired effect.

If your window manager lacks an interface to make a window sticky, try

```
wmctrl -r 0x123456 -b add sticky
```

where 0x123456 is the window ID which you can find with `wmctrl -l` (look for the window in the list) or `xwininfo` (click on the window). You can also use `:SELECT:` instead of a number and click on the window after running the command. Changing the stickyness from outside the window manager may or may not work depending on the window manager, I don't know what precisely makes it work.